# Which replica of input block is processed in mapper?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I create a simple I/O monitoring system for MapReduce jobs written in Java. So at Map stage of the job I want to log information about locations of processed data.

MapReduce job at Map stage process input split which consists of several file blocks in HDFS.
That blocks have several (usually 3) replicas.

Does it possible to know which replicas of these blocks have been used while reading in Mapper?
In other words can I get full path to the particular file in local file system from which Mapper reads?

Answer (score 1):

In HDFS the blocks are replicated and the namenode do not have any information on which is replica. It uses a block to perform an operation based on network latency and load in that specific machine.

The file in HDFS is divided into blocks. The full path of file in hdfs is stored as namenode metadata. Each block is identified by a block id.

The value of the property `dfs.namenode.name.dir` in `hdfs-site.xml` gives the location on where all the blocks are stored.

Based on your requirement, if you want to get the path in local file system where the block is stored, read the value of this property, identify the block id by reading namenode metadata, then you'll be able to find the exact block in local file system that refers to a hdfs file programmatically.